# How many CPU cycles does it take to execute my simple function?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, profiling

For educational purposes I want to know how many CPU cycles it takes to execute a function after it has been optimized (at different levels) and compiled. Is there a way to analyze the code or the executable to get a reproducable answer? I'm using Eclipse Luna, with MinGW on 64 bit Windows 7 Pro.

```
#include <math.h>
#include "main.h"

#define EPS 1e-15 // EPS a small number ~ machine precision
#define R2D 57.295779513082320876798154814105   //multiply radian with R2D to get degrees
#define D2R 0.01745329251994329576923690768489  //multiply degrees with D2R to get radians
#define TWO_PI 6.283185307179586476925286766559 //2*Pi


double _stdcall CourseInitial (double *lat1, double *lon1, double *lat2, double *lon2)
{
    double radLat1     = D2R *  *lat1;
    double radLat2     = D2R *  *lat2;
    double radDeltaLon = D2R * (*lon2 - *lon1);
    double tc = 0;

    if (cos(radLat1) < EPS) {  // EPS a small number ~ machine precision
        if (radLat1 > 0) {
          tc = 180;            // Starting at N pole
        } else {
          tc = 0;              // Starting at S pole
        }
    } else {
      // Calculate true course [-180, 180)
      tc = R2D * atan2(sin(radDeltaLon),
                       cos(radLat1) * tan(radLat2) - sin(radLat1) * cos(radDeltaLon)
                      );
    }

    if (fabs(tc) < EPS) {
        tc = 0;  //Prevents fmod(tc, 360) from returning 360 due to rounding error
    } else {
        tc += 360; //tc [180, 540)
    }
    return fmod(tc, 360); // returns tc [0, 360)
}

int main(void)
{
    double lat1 = 67
    double lon1 = 15;
    double lat2 = 71;
    double lon2 = 24;
    double tc = 0;
    tc = CourseInitial(&lat1, &lon1, &lat2, &lon2);
    printf("The course from point 1 to 2 is: %.1f\n", tc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the generated assembly code, and then read the CPU manual for each instruction, and you should be able to make an educated guess.

Comment: Without knowing what processor (and probably what code compiler generates, what code is in C runtime library, etc), it's impossible to tell. I could measure it, but that would tell me on MY processor, not on your processor. You'd probably have to run the function through a loop since the overhead of measuring the time would probably be about the same as the function itself (on my processor, a RDTSC (Read TimeStamp Counter) will take about 40 clock-cycles, and I expect your function will be in the order of 50-200 clockcycles, without actually compiling and looking at the code.

Comment: You could get the assembly instructions by diss-assembling the optimized code and then look up how many CPU cycles each instruction takes.  It depends on the hardware, here's one resource: http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Comment: You could run only your function with the system idle while looking at the CPU performance counters I suppose, but that'd only get you a very rough estimate.

Comment: Why the downvote? Surely there is a better way to figure this out than manually counting cycles with the CPU manual next to me? The exact count is of no importance (hence it is irrelevant which CPU it is calculated on). The importance of the question is how to come up with the answer, so I can learn to write better code.

Comment: + Counting cycles with the CPU manual was the way to do it, 30 years ago. Not now - CPU developers have to stay ahead of their competitors, and they do it with all kinds of wizardry. Even so, it's a really good idea to get used to the assembly language your compiler generates, so you can stay away from stuff that makes it struggle.

Comment: Many architectures include combined sincos instruction or library function -- thus it may not make sense to factor out cos(radlat2) out of the equation. Multiplications are essentially free and sin or cos computations are faster than tan. Other first level optimizations would include getting rid of the last ftan and the first cos calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

#define EPS 1e-15 // EPS a small number ~ machine precision
#define R2D 57.295779513082320876798154814105   //multiply radian with R2D to get degrees
#define D2R 0.01745329251994329576923690768489  //multiply degrees with D2R to get radians
#define TWO_PI 6.283185307179586476925286766559 //2*Pi


double CourseInitial (double *lat1, double *lon1, double *lat2, double *lon2)
{
    double radLat1     = D2R *  *lat1;
    double radLat2     = D2R *  *lat2;
    double radDeltaLon = D2R * (*lon2 - *lon1);
    double tc = 0;

    if (cos(radLat1) < EPS) {  // EPS a small number ~ machine precision
        if (radLat1 > 0) {
          tc = 180;            // Starting at N pole
        } else {
          tc = 0;              // Starting at S pole
        }
    } else {
      // Calculate true course [-180, 180)
      tc = R2D * atan2(sin(radDeltaLon),
                       cos(radLat1) * tan(radLat2) - sin(radLat1) * cos(radDeltaLon)
                      );
    }

    if (fabs(tc) < EPS) {
        tc = 0;  //Prevents fmod(tc, 360) from returning 360 due to rounding error
    } else {
        tc += 360; //tc [180, 540)
    }
    return fmod(tc, 360); // returns tc [0, 360)
}

struct LatLon
{
    double lat, lon; 
};

struct CoursePoint
{
    LatLon a, b;
};

const int SIZE = 1000000;

CoursePoint cps[SIZE];
double tc[SIZE];

LatLon RandomLatLon()
{
    LatLon l;
    l.lat = rand() % 90;
    l.lon = rand() % 60;
    return l;
}

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}

int main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
    cps[i].a = RandomLatLon();
    cps[i].b = RandomLatLon();
    }
    unsigned long long t = rdtsc();
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
    tc[i] = CourseInitial(&cps[i].a.lat, &cps[i].a.lon, &cps[i].b.lat, &cps[i].b.lon);
    }
    t = rdtsc() - t;
    printf("Time=%f\n", t/(double)SIZE);
    double tot = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
    tot += tc[i];
    }
    printf("Sum of courses: %f\n", tot);

    return 0;
}
```

It comes to around 850-1000 cycles per iteration.

If you don't run a long loop like this, spurious things will affect the actual performance. Compiler optimisation options make a small difference, adding -ffast-math makes a bigger difference than -O0 vs -O3. Different compilers also make a bit of a difference.

g++ 4.9.2:

```
-O0    1013 cycles
-O1     879 cycles
-O2     878 cycles
-O3     877 cycles
Add -ffast-math:
-O0     978
-O1     855  (re-run gives 890)
-O2     882
-O3     848  (re-run gives 850)
```

Clang++ (3.7 as of a couple of weeks back):

```
-O0     998 cycles
-O1     954 cycles
-O2     955 cycles
-O3     957 cycles
Add -ffast-math:
-O0     967
-O1     872
-O2     865
-O3     875
```

Clang++ as of yesterday:

```
-O0    1001 cycles
-O1     956 cycles
-O2     948 cycles
-O3     949 cycles
Add -ffast-math:
-O0     969
-O1     871
-O2     869
-O3     873
```

Note that differences of less than 10 clock-cycles is probably not statistically significant. I did reported a run once, but I tried several times before that to ensure that most of the time, I got the same(ish) answer.

Note that a different processor will give quite different results, and different compiler versions clearly show some differences.

Edit: Just for fun, I'll rewrite it as Pascal and run it through my Pascal compiler to see what that does too.

Code compiled with my Pascal compiler takes 881 clock-cycles with -O2 (highest level available).

FreePascal, which is the "official" Linux Pascal compiler doesn't have an available clock-cycle counter, so I just did `time ./course`, and it comes out about 0.44s, where my code from my compiler is 0.37s.

Comment: Are there any tools that can analyse the assembly code and return a theoretical result without the code actually beeing run?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - and it would probably not give you the right answer, since the figuring out what happens and how long it takes is very complex in modern CPU's - for example, dependencies between results, cache hit/miss ratios, and so on.

Comment: @ArildMJohannessen: to do that, it would have to simulate the execution of the code. There is no shortcut, because If there were a shortcut, then the CPU itself could use that same shortcut and be done in less time than what the shortcut calculated. So which time is right? They can't both be. A good simulator for the instruction set is the CPU itself, though you might get a low-speed approximation using *valgrind*.

Comment: Yes, to calculate it, at the very least you need to go over each instruction, figure out how many clock-cycles it takes, and how many times it gets executed, and then figure out how many instructions can be executed in parallel. That would give you the ideal time of execution in clock-cycles. But in the real world, most code will not execute in ideal time, since the processor needs to load data and instructions from memory, the memory management unit need to read page-tables, etc, etc. A single memory read on a modern CPU, even in ideal circumstances can take longer than 100 instructions.